# Print name or definition of callable in PHP

Tags: php, callable

Callables in PHP can be in a lot of forms, like an object, an array, or a string containing a function name.

If I got a callable like this in a variable how can I print some user friendly "definition" of it in the log.

Think of this code:

```
call_user_func($callable);
$logger->log("Provided callable " . (string) $callable . " called");
```

Problem is, this raises error, for example array to string conversion error. What is the best way to print out something useful about that callable?

Comment: Have you considered [var_export()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)? Or is that too much detail?

Comment: @dave it is too much detail if an object is involved. Ideally is would be just class name, function/method name or a descriptive string if its an anonymous function. I thing I can write custom code to handle all possibilities but don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

Very old question but since i just used this to log some info, i thought it could use some clarification.

The comment by @Fabian Picone is a bit misleading.

The type hint actually works with string (arrays too), but the string MUST be an existing method or function (if you add `function foo() {}` in your code it will work). And that is, it must actually be callable. The error message is not that intuitive.

See this answer too https://stackoverflow.com/a/63289789/7409925.

This is my take that i'm using for logging (expanded from @Seb's), adding support for invokables and removing unnecessary `trim`'s:

```
function getCallableName(callable $callable) {
    switch (true) {
        case is_string($callable) && strpos($callable, '::'):
            return '[static] ' . $callable;
        case is_string($callable):
            return '[function] ' . $callable;
        case is_array($callable) && is_object($callable[0]):
            return '[method] ' . get_class($callable[0])  . '->' . $callable[1];
        case is_array($callable):
            return '[static] ' . $callable[0]  . '::' . $callable[1];
        case $callable instanceof Closure:
            return '[closure]';
        case is_object($callable):
            return '[invokable] ' . get_class($callable);
        default:
            return '[unknown]';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

> ```
> function getCallableName($callable) {
>     if (is_string($callable)) {
>         return trim($callable);
>     } else if (is_array($callable)) {
>         if (is_object($callable[0])) {
>             return sprintf("%s::%s", get_class($callable[0]), trim($callable[1]));
>         } else {
>             return sprintf("%s::%s", trim($callable[0]), trim($callable[1]));
>         }
>     } else if ($callable instanceof Closure) {
>         return 'closure';
>     } else {
>         return 'unknown';
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Your typehint is already callable, so why you check is_string and is_array? Passing string or array raises fatal error.

Comment: Plain strings and arrays are callables too. You an check what's a callable here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Comment: A string is type of string, not callable. Did you tested it? I tested your code 1:1 see https://3v4l.org/YdlTh

Comment: You are absolutely right, that typehint is wrong, my bad. I'll edit the answer. Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by an answer of @Bigdot https://stackoverflow.com/a/68113840/6916271 I created 2 methods, which could be useful when we need to retrieve the context of callable.
I used result together with Monolog, but it is also possible to use it with print_r(), json_encode(), var_dump() or var_export() if you need to convert it to string.
The main difference here compared to the answer above is extended information about closure, which might be needed during an investigation.

```
/**
 * Retrieve the context of callable for debugging purposes
 *
 * @param callable $callable
 * @return array
 */
private function getCallableContext(callable $callable): array
{
    switch (true) {
        case \is_string($callable) && \strpos($callable, '::'):
            return ['static method' => $callable];
        case \is_string($callable):
            return ['function' => $callable];
        case \is_array($callable) && \is_object($callable[0]):
            return ['class' => \get_class($callable[0]), 'method' => $callable[1]];
        case \is_array($callable):
            return ['class' => $callable[0], 'static method' => $callable[1]];
        case $callable instanceof \Closure:
            try {
                $reflectedFunction = new \ReflectionFunction($callable);
                $closureClass = $reflectedFunction->getClosureScopeClass();
                $closureThis = $reflectedFunction->getClosureThis();
            } catch (\ReflectionException $e) {
                return ['closure' => 'closure'];
            }

            return [
                'closure this'  => $closureThis ? \get_class($closureThis) : $reflectedFunction->name,
                'closure scope' => $closureClass ? $closureClass->getName() : $reflectedFunction->name,
                'static variables' => $this->formatVariablesArray($reflectedFunction->getStaticVariables()),
            ];
        case \is_object($callable):
            return ['invokable' => \get_class($callable)];
        default:
            return ['unknown' => 'unknown'];
    }
}

/**
 * Format variables array for debugging purposes in order to avoid huge objects dumping
 *
 * @param array $data
 * @return array
 */
private function formatVariablesArray(array $data): array
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (\is_object($value)) {
            $data[$key] = \get_class($value);
        } elseif (\is_array($value)) {
            $data[$key] = $this->formatVariablesArray($value);
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

In we use logger

```
try {
    \call_user_func($callable);
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    $logger->log(
        'Error occurred',
        ['exception' => $e, 'callable' => $this->getCallableContext($callable)]
    );
    //In case we can use string only
    $logger->log('Error occurred: ' . \print_r($this->getCallableContext($callable), true));
}
```