# PHP Type hinting callable function

Tags: php

Ok, so I have this class method defined to take a callback and I've type hinted it as callable as per the type hinting documentation.

```
protected function AddTransformData(array $definition,array $where,callable $callback){
    $this->transforms[]=[$definition,$where,$callback];
}
```

Here is an example of where I might call this function. Using the array syntax for passing a method and object as a callback.

```
public function __construct(PostalZoneMapping $pzm){
    $this->pzm=$pzm;
    $this->AddTransformData(Countries::region,['filter'],[$this,'TransformId']);
    $this->AddTransformData(PostalZones::id,['filter'],[$this,'TransformId']);
    $this->ReceiveData();
}
```

This throws an error, image below, complaining about argument 3 not being callable, but an array. Logically, I guess this makes sense, as it is array, but it's an array of a callable function - surely it must detect that it's a callback?

Is this a PHP quirk or am I doing something wrong?

[image: Exception from passing an callable array as a callable parameter]

Comment: What is generating the exception?  I've tried to create something similar and not been able to reproduce the results.  Can you create a simple set of code to reproduce this error in the question.

Comment: Isn't this just and IDE error? Is it real Exception encountered by actually RUNNING the code? What IDE is this - maybe it doesn't understand callable arrays notation.

Comment: Which visability has your 'TransformId' method? Isn't it private or protected?

Comment: @IvanShumakov as per documentation: `Accessing protected and private methods from within a class is allowed. ` - So even if it is private in the context of this class it should be valid callable?

Comment: Figured it out when I created test code, the callable was private, and that's why it threw an exception. It's not valid in this context because we're calling a method in an abstract class.

Comment: Ok, turns out it was not in a context of a single class but parent - child. Then it has to be at least protected so it can be called in the parent.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function __construct(PostalZoneMapping $pzm){
    $this->pzm=$pzm;
    $method = 'TransformId';
    $callable = fn() => $this->$method();
    $this->AddTransformData(Countries::region,['filter'], $callable);
    $this->AddTransformData(PostalZones::id,['filter'], $callable);
    $this->ReceiveData();
}
```

if you have PHP version below 7.4 then instead of this:

```
$callable = fn() => $this->$method();
```

do this:

```
$callable = function() use ($method) { $this->$method() };
```

You also can receive an arguments:

```
$callable = fn($param) => $this->$method($param);
```

or

```
$callable = function($param) use ($method) { $this->$method($param)};
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `TransformId` is not a method on that class. Maybe its a typo, maybe its a property but not a method.

In order for array to be a valid callback it has to be: `A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1.`

This works:

```
class A {
  function __construct() {
    $this->asd2([$this, 'asd']);
  }
  private function asd() {}

  public function asd2(callable $c) {}
}

$a = new A();
```

This doesnt:

```
class A {
  function __construct() {
    $this->asd2([$this, 'somethingElse']);
  }
  private function asd() {}

  public function asd2(callable $c) {}
}

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to A::asd2() must be callable, array given, called in
```

If I'm wrong - paste whole class code including `TransformId` method.

Answer (score 1):

I create some test code to reproduce the error, having noticed that I declared the callback as private! This code won't work, but will work if you change the TransformId method to protected or public.

```
<?php

abstract class CommonDataInterface{
    private $transforms=[];
    /**
     * Adds a callback that transform data 
     *
     * @param array $definition Definition, where, if matches, callback is called.
     * @param array $where Where to transform data, array values one or more of 'set','insert' or'filter'
     * @param callable $callback Function that takes value as parameter, and returns transformed value.
     * @return void
     */
    protected function AddTransformData(array $definition,array $where,callable $callback){
        $this->transforms[]=[$definition,$where,$callback];
    }
}


class Api_PostalZoneMapping extends CommonDataInterface{
    private $pzm;

    public function __construct($pzm){
        $this->pzm=$pzm;
        $this->AddTransformData(['blah'],['filter'],[$this,'TransformId']);
        $this->AddTransformData(['blah2'],['filter'],[$this,'TransformId']);
        //$this->ReceiveData();
    }

    private function TransformId($data){
        if($data==-1)
            return null;
        return $data;
    }
}

$p=new Api_PostalZoneMapping('not relevant for test');
```